# How to open/expand a comboxbox programmatically in Windows 8 store app?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Setting the focus on combobox doesn't do it. Any other way to make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
combobox.IsDropDownOpen = true
```